# offline synchronisation logic

Tags: dropbox, synchronization, offline, node-webkit

I am developping a stand-alone writer app in JS and node-webkit that should be able to store the production locally when offline and sync with a user-based cloud service, like dropbox. Rigth now the writings are saved in an object and written locally in a file.

Now, each user is alone on his writings, so there is no chance that somebody is editing at the same time, so i don't need to sync live from server to client. BUT i need the app to be flexible with internet connectivity (designed for people of the remote), so that mean that somebody could start it offline, start editing, then get connection, then loose it again. And sometime not having internet for couple of days, and keep editing. And all of this should sync when connection comes and go.

The trick is, sometime my user will edit on an other terminal - other computer or, in the futur, mobile device, and all of this should sync somehow.

I thought using Dropbox datastore, but they can't handle an offline start, so it looses all interest.

Right now, this is my logic : every sheet has a 'last edited' timestamp and a 'last editor' id that every version of my program generates on first start. So every time you got the net back i download the full db from the net, and compare each sheet whith the object stored locally. If they have the same id, that mean nobody else has touched it, and the local version on this computer still stands. other wise, i need to face conflict resolution.

My question is a bit too large : do you have any hint or idea, or links on how to implement such a sync process, or how to make it more efficient from my lead ?

Comment: Firebase I say here.

Comment: I though about that as well, but i'd like to let the user be responsible of his own data : i don't want a centralized sync service but let the people backup their data on their personnal cloud. So dropbox sounded the best, or maybe GDrive.

Comment: On this case the least I can recommend to you is to save a guid or something like that on every write in the database. When your client comes online compare the local guid with the database one. This way you will not download the whole database for nothing.